# Transfer files using PuTTy in Windows

Tags: windows, putty

I have two computers and both of them are windows 7 machines. I want to use PuTTy to transfer files from one to the other.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about windows software on windows computers belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use putty while both are Windows machines ?

1. You can use Windows share, get faster transfer with password protection.
2. Use any FTP server like filezilla, if you don't want to use Windows share.
3. If you need encryption, use FTP with ssh connection, this also possible by filezilla FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Won't work as putty does not include file transfer (pscp does but putty itself does not), putty (and pscp) is a client and will only connect to a server so one of the machines must be a ssh server and getting windows to be a ssh server is a royal pita. you could use an intermediate ssh server, but unless you have one already, doing something else would be easier.